# can an angularjs repeater control table column width?

Tags: angularjs

Can i use a repeater to control the width of my table columns in angularjs?
[col ng-repeat](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/gTUZd/13/)

```
 <colgroup>
                            <col ng-repeat="th in eventCollection.head" ng-style="width:{{th.width}}" />
                            <!--<col span="1" style="width: 5px;">
                            <col span="1" style="width: 100px;">
                            <col span="1" style="width: 20px;">
                            <col span="1" style="width: 20px;">
                            <col span="1" style="width: 20px;">
                            <col span="1" style="width: 20px;">-->
                        </colgroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lose the double braces:

```html
<col ng-repeat="th in eventCollection.head" span="1" ng-style="{ width: th.width }">
```

Comment: That produces the following output in html. and doesn't seem to size the columns:<col class="ng-scope" ng-style="width: th.width" ng-repeat="th in eventCollection.head">

Comment: @VBAHole - It needs single braces. Mea culpa. Updated.